# Issue for For and IF Loops not working as expected

Tags: r

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong on this simple loop....

```
test <- c(1,2,3)


gio <- 0
for (i in length(test)){
  if  (test[i] == 1) {
    gio[i] <-  "1" 
  } else gio[i] <- "2"
}
```

The very weird results I get is:

```
gio
[1] "0" NA  "2"
```

Which doesn't make any sense to me...

Any clue?

Comment: `for (i in 1:length(test))` or `for (i in seq_along(test))`

Comment: @HubertL has the correction you need, but, I'd encourage you to be more careful with `gio`.  You initialize it as a length 1 numeric.  But then you start filling it with character values.  In addition, I'm surprised that `gio[i] <- "1"` even works: looks like `R` is allowing to concatenate values in a strange way that I didn't even know would work.  Better to initialize to a length that makes sense, e.g. `gio <- rep(NA_character_, length(test))`.  If you don't fill the whole thing, you can do `na.omit(gio)` to remove the `NA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the first line of your for loop to be

```
for(i in 1:length(test)){
```

or

```
for(i in seq_along(test)){
```

There are other ways as well but those two are the most common.

Your loop as written only runs one time and uses `i = length(test)`.  So what happens is you initialize gio to 0.  Then you run the code with `i=3` so obviously `test[3]` isn't 1 so you run the 'else' portion and ultimately say

```
gio[3] <- "2"
```

Before that line all you had was `gio = 0` so now it says "oh there need to be at least three elements so it sets the third element to "2" like you told it to.  Since this is character it converts the 0 that was already present to "0" since vectors can only be a single type.  The second element was never initialized so it is NA.

Comment: Thank  you, I knew the solution was more obvious than I thought. Silly mistake.